# Strange object returned when using content picker

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco

Im currently making usercontrol for umbraco that takes all `Nodes` indside a `Node` names "Features"...
And it all works perfekt, until i wanted to get content from the "Content Picker" property (named linkToPage).

When i tried to use `GetProperty("linkToPage").Value`, I got an error about it being an object. 
So i then added it to a `var` and debugged, and saw it returned somthing a bit strange...

```
var linkIdVar = child.GetProperty("linkToPage");
```

Returns:

```
-   linkIdVar   {1081}      umbraco.interfaces.IProperty {umbraco.NodeFactory.Property}
    -   [umbraco.NodeFactory.Property]  {1081}  umbraco.NodeFactory.Property
        Alias   "linkToPage"    string
        Value   "1081"  string
        +   Version {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  System.Guid
        +   Non-Public members      
    Alias   "linkToPage"    string
    Value   "1081"  string
    +   Version {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  System.Guid
```

And i can't seem to get the Value to a Int without getting error about it being an object...

So does anyone know how to get arround this, or know a better way to get the page from a `Content Picker`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to unbox the value to an integer, like so:

```
var val = (int) child.GetProperty("linkToPage").Value;
```

However, if the content of the property value is not an integer, but a string, as the debugging information seems to indicate, then you need to convert to an integer, like so:

```
var val = int.Parse(child.GetProperty("linkToPage").Value as string);
```

Comment: That may be because you expect an integer as the contents of `linkToPage`, which as it seems is not always the case. Try to see what the contents of the property are at the point of the exception.

Comment: ahh found the solution, have to check if its empty before i get it...
Thanks alot!